# I complained by accident will I still be tested by Allah(SWT)?

Tags: practical-islam, evil-thoughts

I had bad thoughts and thought that I was complaining I was saying I just want to live a better life but I thought I wasn't complaining will I still be held accountable for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad thoughts happens to Anyone . It is satan who whispers to have bad thoughts , feel ungrateful , feel I adequate, feel insecure , feel like you will not be forgiven . Be aware they are not from Allah . Recite and remember Allah and seek refuge from Satan.

When Allah loves you , it doesn’t mean he showers you luxuries of this world . Those he loved before you , they did not have luxuries of this world . Look at the life of the prophets . When Allah loves you , Allah gives you contentment of the heart .

The world will never be perfect for anyone . Everyone will be tested with loss of life , wealth and so on . Most loved by Allah tested with hardship like we can’t imagine . You want to succeed strengthen your relationship with Allah

Comment: Is saying I want to live a better life complaining?